# Return function that returns a reference

Tags: rust

I want to write a simple memoization function.

```rs
fn memoize<K: Eq + Hash, V: Clone>(mut func: impl FnMut(&K) -> V) -> impl FnMut(K) -> V {
  let mut cache = HashMap::new();
  |key| {
    cache
      .entry(key)
      .or_insert_with_key(|k| func(k))
      .clone()
  }
}
```

`Eq + Hash` bound on argument seems reasonable, but `Clone` on return value seems to be unnecessary. Ideally the signature would be:

```rs
fn memoize<K: Eq + Hash, V>(mut func: impl FnMut(&K) -> V) -> impl FnMut(K) -> &mut V
```

Which requires specifying lifetime of the returned reference (makes sense).

Ideally the `&mut V` should live for as long as the ref to the function lives (or something like that: `&'a mut impl FnMut(K) -> &'a mut V`)

Since impls for Fn traits are unstable, and if I wanted to stay within Fn traits (not writing my struct with some `fn call(&'a mut self, key: K) -> &'a mut V`) is there a way to do that in stable Rust?

Comment: I'm not sure returning a `&mut V` makes sense for a memoized function (which is normally pure). Why not `&V`?

Comment: It might also make sense to continue taking `&K` by reference instead of by value, but then you need `K: Clone`. It lets you avoid the cloning in the (presumably common) case that the key is already in the map.

Comment: @Thomas Sure, but since I have the &mut from hash map entry, might as well pass &mut to the caller. Reasonably mutating result of memoized call doesn't make a lot of sense, but I'm just trying to offer as permittable contract as I can allow. Just as well it might not make sense for pure function to be `FnMut`, but since I can allow that, why restrict the caller.

Comment: I'm not sure this design is possible without interior mutability (`Cell` and friends). The returned function returns references (mutable or not) into `cache`, which means you can't add anything to the cache in a second call.

Comment: Yeah, I've encountered that limitation with the entry API before, where it takes ownership of the key no matter if it is already present. In this case I don't really care about it tbh. And I guess this results in tradeoff of hashing twice or allocating (if key cannot be just moved)

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't be able to add anything to `cache` until you hold a reference to the `V`. 

It seems so close to be able to be tracked by borrow checker. But yeah, whatever. Thanks a lot tho :P.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intentions, but you _can_ add a lifetime to the return impl type. Something like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=56270398c51a51832ab4f55f6fc8f963)?.

Comment: The problem really is in ensuring that the cache is borrowed for the lifetime of the returned reference, but since the cache is captured environment Rust does not permit the returned reference to escape the arising `FnMut`.  If you instead use an explicit struct it works fine, though using a method is slightly less ergonomic than direct invocation: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a693b49da6283f766ab4852d29cd7fc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. Even with a manual implementation of `FnMut` it would not be possible, unless we make `Output` a Generic Associated Type:

```rust
pub trait GatifiedFnMut<Args: std::marker::Tuple> {
    type Output<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output<'_>;
}

pub struct Memoized<K, V, F> {
    cache: HashMap<K, V>,
    func: F,
}

impl<K: Eq + Hash, V, F: FnMut(&K) -> V> GatifiedFnMut<(K,)> for Memoized<K, V, F> {
    type Output<'a> = &'a mut V
    where
        Self: 'a;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, (key,): (K,)) -> Self::Output<'_> {
        self.cache.entry(key).or_insert_with_key(&mut self.func)
    }
}
```

(**Note:** This can be worked around even without GATs, but not with the current `FnOnce`/`FnMut`/`Fn` traits, or at least very uncomfortably, see below linked question).

[More information can be found at users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-closure-cannot-return-a-reference-to-data-moved-into-closure/72655?u=chrefr).